# Angular : event.key is not coming as shft+tab on press of Shift+ Tab Key

Tags: javascript, angular

We have a dropdown menu that opens and closes on click and displays a list of li items.

We're facing an issue with the focus when using the keyboard. When the user presses the Tab key, the focus moves from one li item to the next. However, when the focus reaches the last li item (5th item) and the user presses Shift + Tab, the focus does not move to the previous li item (4th li item) as expected.

we added a keyboard event listener to detect the Tab and shift-tab keys. However, we're facing an issue where the key property returns only the Shift key when the user presses Shift + Tab,or Tab key when the user presses Tab+shift and the shift-tab action is not being executed as expected.

```
        <ul>
  <li tabindex="0" #lastAccountListItem class="account-nav--list-item app-font-regular-18" *ngFor="let accountItem of mainMenu.accountTabList; index as i"
    (mouseenter)="optionHighlightIndex=i">
    {{accountItem.displayLabel}} ----- has 4 items, shift+tab works fine 4th item
  </li>


  <li tabindex="0" *ngIf="isArchived" #isArchivedFocus class="account-nav--list-item account-archive-link app-font-regular-18"
    (mouseenter)="optionHighlightIndex=mainMenu.accountTabList.length">
    {{mainMenu.archivedTab.label | titlecase}}  --- has 1 item only, when focus come here, it doesn't go to previous li item
  </li>
</ul>
        
    
    onArcKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
      if (event.key === 'Tab') {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.archievedDropdownItem.nativeElement.focus();
      } else if (event.shiftKey && event.key === 'Tab') { --- issue is here 
        event.preventDefault();
        this.lastAccountListItem.nativeElement.focus();
      }
    }
```

Also, for testing purposes, I tried single events for Shift. When the focus is on the 5th li item and I press Shift, the focus directly goes to the first li item instead of the 4th li item.

```
(event.shiftKey ) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        this.lastAccountListItem.nativeElement.focus();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

each key will call event handler separately. For example for `Shift + Tab`. `Shift` call event handler once and after that `tab` will call it.
You can save previous key in a variable and focus element if current key is Tab and previous was `shift`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public handleKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent, index: string): void {
    const e = event.which || event.keyCode;
    switch (e) {
      case event.shiftKey && 9: // 9 represents tabkey code
        // your code goes here
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).